# Check intersections between points and polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two data layers, one with points and one with polygons. Both layers have ID's and I would like to check whether the points with ID x lay inside or outside the polygon with ID x.

Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Marie

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution which gives you a comma separated list in the python console is to run a small script from the python console:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()

for a in layers[0].getFeatures():
    for b in layers[1].getFeatures():
        if a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()):
            print a.id(),",",b.id()
```

This should produce a result of cases where one feature intersects the other. The order of the layers did not matter in my testing, however, both layers had to use the same coordinate reference system, so you might need to re-project your data if both layers have different reference systems. This worked for points in polygons and polygons intersecting polygons (I'm sure it would work with lines as well).

Answers such as this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168266/pyqgis-a-geometry-intersectsb-geometry-wouldnt-find-any-intersections may help with further refinement of such a script, and was a primary source on this answer.